# Use requestBodyProcessor after base64Decode

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

ModSecurity allows us to use different request body processors (e.g. for XML or JSON). My question is, is it possible to first decode a body that holds a base64 encoded string

`eyJuYW1lIjoiSm9obiIsICJhZ2UiOjI1fQ==`

which translates to

`{"name":"John", "age":25}`

and after that use `requestBodyProcessor=JSON`?

I tried different rules with transformations and so on, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible, because:

- body processor needs to be activated in phase 1, this cannot by done in any later phase
- REQUEST_BODY variable is populated at the start of phase 2 so it's not accessible in phase 1

There IS a way how to achieve what you need but it's a little complex and not backward compatible with existing rules using parsed JSON data. You can do this:

- disable JSON body processor
- create new rule which runs at the beginning of phase 2 (before all other rules) and which runs a Lua script
- create a Lua script which first decodes base64 data from REQUEST_BODY, then runs a JSON parser on it and finally expose parsed data via some variable in TX collection

Comment: Here an additional conversation in the mailing list concerning a similar problem: https://sourceforge.net/p/mod-security/mailman/mod-security-users/thread/251433A6-1DE5-4564-92E6-CA27BF0B0DC3%40anduin.net/#msg36289204